# PHP form sending blank emails every 15 mins?

Tags: php, jquery, forms

I have a strange problem with my PHP contact form, every 15 minutes or so I get a blank email and receive them though the day?! When I fill out the form I get the details sent to me at once and all of the fields are filled out fine.

I use PHP for the form and the jQuery validate for the validation, the form works and so does the validation but since I am not strong with PHP maybe it's the process that's not right?

**form.php** - *from:* https://1stwebdesigner.com/php-contact-form-html/

```
  <?php
   $name = $_POST['name'];
   $email = $_POST['email'];
   $phone = $_POST['phone'];
   $call = $_POST['call'];
   $website = $_POST['website'];
   $priority = $_POST['priority'];
   $type = $_POST['type'];
   $message = $_POST['message'];
   $formcontent=" From: $name \n Phone: $phone \n Call Back: $call \n Website: $website \n Priority: $priority \n Type: $type \n Message: $message";
   $recipient = "youremail@here.com";
   $subject = "Contact Form";
   $mailheader = "From: $email \r\n";
   mail($recipient, $subject, $formcontent, $mailheader) or die("Error!");
   echo "Thank You!";
  ?>
```

I had to take the form down as I receive so many mails a day. The `$recipient` was set to my email but left it as a dummy address for this post.

Comment: you've been targeted then (cron bot). You need to integrate a captcha and/or a checkbox that needs to be checked in order to execute. You should also check for any empty arrays. Look as this as "one" possible solution. Check your access logs also and deny access to them.

Comment: Look for WordPress plugins that help protect your site from being spammed

Comment: Oh I see, it only started the other day besides that it was all OK. Also I didn't think it was a bot as it didn't send me any SPAM.

Comment: @victor, I don't use WordPress for the site.

Comment: The glaring omission from your code is checking for the `submit` button or empty `$_POST`.

Comment: there's no validation here. you can't only depend on the Jquery validate, u need to validate in the server side as well. Maybe have a honeyport field

Comment: @AbraCadaver Ah, I am not a PHP master like you guys so I was not aware of that.

Comment: Seems like [the *(most)* upvoted comment *so far*](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43215119/php-form-sending-blank-emails-every-15-mins#comment73501907_43215119) has been quickly swept under the rug, *as it were*.

Comment: my bad @Hanna, ive been answering a lot of WordPress questions today and you having website issues + the php code got me back in WordPress mode.

Comment: @victor no worries :) I know what it's like sometimes, appreciate the comment either way.

Comment: [You're welcome](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43215119/php-form-sending-blank-emails-every-15-mins#comment73501907_43215119)

Comment: Thank you @Fred -ii- I am new here so can't upvote you or what you call it, your comment helped me out.

Comment: you're welcome @Hanna I'd of submitted an answer, but I may have gotten downvoted for it, seeing that the answer given received one (not by me, I can honestly say). If anything, I'd of posted what is called a "community wiki", and there is no rep gain/loss from one given.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

As per your code snippet. It's nothing to do with 15 mins blank email issue. Your form might been targeted with some bot or malicious script. However, it's really simple form. There are several standard practices for forms but for starters, you may be looking into following links to get the whole idea.

https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_form_complete.asp
https://www.w3schools.com/php/showphp.asp?filename=demo_form_validation_complete

When you are done with this reading, you should be looking into [javascript Form Validation](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_validation.asp) and [Capcha integration](https://www.google.com/recaptcha/intro/). Once you are comfortable with Javascipt Validation, you migh jump to Jquery Validation or jQuery Validation plugins.

Above links are not really end of the world but you shall at least get the idea for basic form submission process.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you Sam, I see I have a lot of work to do, @Fred -ii- also mentioned the bots so I will get rid of the form for now and add it later with extra layer of security. How long does a bot target your site for? If the form is gone will it still visit the site?

Comment: well, you can check your server logs and stats. You should be able to get who is hitting your form URL. It's better idea to simply secure your form. Once bots/scripts keep hitting until you get with a better idea. It's chance that bot stops working, they might stop and may come later to check the same URL. It's better to secure your form to the extent that bot is unable to post automatically. As long as your form is secure, you should be worried about who hit your form.It might be malicious script installed in your browser. In short, secure your form.